# Automated rosdoc_lite execution

Tags: ros, rosdoc-lite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I was wondering whether it is possible to run rosdoc_lite automatically with every catkin_make for my packages, so that supporting documentation is always up-to-date.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203272/automated-rosdoc_lite-execution/) by [Georacer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10641/georacer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2015-02-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally got it!
I don't know why it works, but it does.

```
    add_dependencies(environment ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp ROSLITE_HOOK)
[...]
## Generate Doxygen files
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT rosdoc_output
        COMMAND rosdoc_lite $(rospack find last_letter) -o $(rospack find last_letter)/doc
    )
    add_custom_target(ROSLITE_HOOK DEPENDS rosdoc_output)
```

**EDIT:** In the end, I did it in the following way. The previous didn't work as expected:

```
## Generate package documentation with rosdoc_lite
execute_process(COMMAND rospack find last_letter
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE LAST_LETTER_DIR OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
execute_process(COMMAND rosdoc_lite -o ${LAST_LETTER_DIR}/doc/doxygen_rosdoc_lite ${LAST_LETTER_DIR} )
```

---

Originally posted by [Georacer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10641/georacer/) with karma: 67 on 2015-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-02-19**:
Defining the dependency is what I was trying to explain. Sorry I didn't know enough to fill in the details. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not tried that, myself. But, you can add custom CMake commands to your CMakeLists.txt.

Take a look at [add_custom_command()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html) and [add_custom_target()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html).

**EDIT:** I think you need to define a CMake target, but I am *not* a CMake expert. Something has to depend on your documentation target to cause building it.

You might take a look at how roslint defines its custom commands and targets:

- https://github.com/ros/roslint/blob/master/cmake/roslint-extras.cmake.em

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georacer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10641/georacer/) on 2015-02-17**:
I tried placing this

```
## Generate doxygen documenation files
add_custom_command(OUTPUT tempdoc.txt
    COMMAND touch tempdoc.txt
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    )
```

In my package's CMakeLists just before the *Install* header but nothing came out. Ideas?

**Comment by [Georacer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10641/georacer/) on 2015-02-19**:
After doing further internet searching, I can't find why the OUTPUT syntax of add_custom_command shouldn't work on its own (ie regardless of dependencies). I'm pretty stumped on this one.